# Why reply mail not containing the older threaded mail body in the replied body?

Tags: android, email, jakarta-mail, imap

***Replying mail by calling this function:***

```
private void replyMail() {
       try{
            Store store = session.getStore("gimap");

            store.connect(userEmailId, password);

            Folder folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");

            folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

            Message emailMessage =
                    folder.getMessage(msgNo);
            
            MimeMessage reply = (MimeMessage) emailMessage.reply(false);
            configureMimeMultipart();
            reply.setFrom(new InternetAddress(userEmailId));
            reply.setReplyTo(emailMessage.getReplyTo());

            reply.setText(message);

            reply.setSubject("Re: "+subject);

            setToMailCcBcc(reply);

            Transport.send(reply,reply.getAllRecipients());
            folder.close();
            store.close();
         }catch(MessagingException | IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
 }
```

***Replying to setup:***

```
private void setToMailCcBcc(MimeMessage mm){
    try {
        for (String toEmail : toEmails) {
            toEmail = toEmail.replace(",", "");
            if (isValid(toEmail)) {
                mm.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                        new InternetAddress(toEmail));
            } 

        }
        
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

***MultiPart setup:***

```
private void configureMimeMultipart(){
    MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();
    mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
    mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
    mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
    mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
    mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content- handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
}
```

***NB:*** Replying to mail is working fine, but the issue is in the body part of a replied mail. It doesn't contain the older mails body part.

***Library used:*** Jakarta Mail, GImap

***output:***

[image]

***Expecting output:***

[image]

Comment: I’m not sure on this library, but for the most part: if you want the reply part in th ebody of the email, you have to put it there.

Comment: You mean manually add a body part along with replied msg?

Comment: Not another body part, but in the same body part.  For plain text, it is literally just the words "On Wed, July 28, 2021 at 6:06...." appended as text to the body part.  There's no magic to it.  For HTML it's a bit more of a pain since you have to stitch it into the HTML in a legal way; many clients accomplish it by manipulating the DOM in JavaScript (since their viewer windows tend to be web views).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. let me try this.